# Hibernate META-INF Location wrong?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence.xml

For some weird reason my Hibernate can't find my `persistence.xml` in the META-INF folder. I have following project structure:

- src

  - eu.bsmusin.pupil.project.db.DataBase.java
  - META-INF/persistence.xml

My class `DataBase.java` calls the method

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("LocalUnit");
```

The error says it can't find a persistence unit called `LocalUnit`. I triple checked the name and all other properties and tried multiple example `persistence.xml` files from the internet. I believe, that Hibernate can't find my meta-inf folder for some stupid reason.

Did this happen to anyone or does somebody know how to fix that problem?

Comment: When you create a session factory you should put a context config location.

Comment: Never heard or seen, can you give me some link for an explanation or a short introduction? @RomanC

Comment: Which META-INF is it in? Please add the content of `persistence.xml`.

Comment: What is this `src` folder? How are things run?

Comment: src is my sourcefolder in which i have all my java classes. Its direclty in the project folder. So the full folderstructure would be:  

Project/src/eu/bsmusin/pupil/project/db/DataBase.java

while eu is the first package. src is the sourcefolder and Project is my projectfolder containing the whole project. src is containing the folder META-INF which contains my persistence.xml

Comment: Check the War file where the `persistence.xml` and check with my answer whether it  in right place.

Answer (score 0):

In all cases, persistence.xml always resides in `{root-of-persistence-unit}/META-INF/ directory`. For example,

```
foo.war:
WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml  //good
WEB-INF/classes/com/foo123/jpa/Project.class
WEB-INF/web.xml
index.jsp
```

You may also package entity classes and `persistence.xml` inside a library jar, which is packaged inside the war: WEB-INF/lib

```
foo.war:
WEB-INF/lib/my-entities.jar
WEB-INF/web.xml
index.jsp
```

my-entities.jar:

```
META-INF/persistence.xml  //good
com/foo123/jpa/Project.class
```

**If you are using maven project** :

`src/main/resources` is the place. When it comes to `persistence.xml` it should be placed in the `META-INF` folder. So to conclude: `src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml.`

Comment: i have a normal java project which is gonna run as a jar later. i am not using war. It is a very simple setup and i don't even have entitiy classes yet or smth like that. i am just trying to build up a databaseconnection by creating a entitymanagerfactory based on my persistence.xml which are both located in the same normal java project

Comment: @Basti build your jar file and check where the `persistence file` it should be there in `META-INF/persistence.xml`

Comment: it is. thats the weird thing. its not the first time i work with hibernate but that the first time that the setup isnt working :o